# VBA Type Mismatch when assigning column to array on 2nd loop

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

As in the subject I have a problem. The below code works fine on the first loop but then on the second loop of `For Each key In dict.Keys` I get a **type mismatch error** running the line:

```
data2 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Columns(6).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

I have tried erasing the data2 array before this but it did not work.

EDIT: The code is taking unique entries from a column, filtering each entry and getting the unique entries from the column next to it (while filtered), and some additional data.

Here is the full code:

```
Sub CollectData() '(Database, DataSheet, rN, rP)

Dim data() As Variant, dict As Object, r As Long, key As Variant
Dim data2() As Variant, dict2 As Object, r2 As Long, key2 As Variant, data3()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, RanTable As Range, endRow As Long
Dim Rang1 As Range
Dim ELRCount As Long, TIDCount As Long

Set Database = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ELRDatabase")
Set DataSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

data = DataSheet.UsedRange.Columns(5).Value

For r = 2 To UBound(data)
    dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
Next

'Select Full Table

endRow = DataSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set RanTable = DataSheet.Range("$A$1:$AQ$" & endRow)

With DataSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add key:=RanTable(1, 7), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add key:=RanTable(1, 8), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange RanTable
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

For Each key In dict.Keys

    DataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    RanTable.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=key
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    data2 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Columns(6).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

    For r2 = 2 To UBound(data2)
        dict2(data2(r2, 1)) = Empty
    Next

    For Each key2 In dict2.Keys

        If Database.Range("A2") = "" Then
            Set Rang1 = Database.Range("A2")
        Else
            Set Rang1 = Database.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End If

        data3 = DataSheet.Range("G:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

        Rang1.Value = "rN"
        Rang1.Offset(0, 1).Value = key
        Rang1.Offset(0, 2).Value = key2
        Rang1.Offset(0, 3).Value = RanTable(2, 16)
        Rang1.Offset(0, 4).Value = data3(2, 1)
        Rang1.Offset(0, 5).Value = data3(2, 2)
        Rang1.Offset(0, 6).Value = data3(UBound(data3), 4)
        Rang1.Offset(0, 7).Value = data3(UBound(data3), 5)
        Rang1.Offset(0, 8).Value = "rP"

    Next key2

Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot assign a multi-area range to an array, except by looping over it and filling the array "manually".  When posting code, please consider not double-spacing your lines - it makes it harder to review when there's too much scrolling required.

Comment: @TimWilliams Apologies about the code and thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### Non-Contiguous

Not tested!

The `data2` solution could be something like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CollectData()
    
    '...
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Instead of 'Data2 = DataSheet.UsedRange...' use the following:
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Datasheet.UsedRange.Columns(6)
    getVisibleColumn Data2, rng
     
    ' or just (without 'rng'):
    'getVisibleColumn Data2, Datasheet.UsedRange.Columns(6)
     
    ' and continue with:
    For r2 = 2 To UBound(Data2)
        dict2(Data2(r2, 1)) = Empty
    Next
    '...

End Sub

Sub getVisibleColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, ColumnRange As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ColumnRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ReDim Data(1 To rng.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim cel As Range, i As Long
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        i = i + 1: Data(i, 1) = cel.Value
    Next cel

End Sub
```

A similar (more complicated) approach can be used to get the `data3` solution.